# django web application race-condition on file

Tags: python, django, multithreading, apache, race-condition

I have a django web app that offers a C code editor, the text is sent to another django application hosted in another server which writes the code in a .c file compiles it and send the response back.

The problem is writing and compiling the file causes a race-condition problem when the application is used with multiple users.

this is how i send the data:

```
def comp(request):   
encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(request.POST)    
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://serverIpadress/compile/?' + encoded_data)    
tml = url.read()
return HttpResponse(tml)
```

this is how the data is processed on the second django app

```
def compile(request):
data2=urllib.urlencode({'': request.GET.get('content','')})
request.encoding ='koi8-r'
data=request.GET.get('content','')
handle=open('/home/user/file.c','r+')
handle.write(request.GET['content'])
handle.close()
res = commands.getstatusoutput('gcc -Wall /home/user/file.c -o /home/user/file;home/user/file')
return HttpResponse(res)
```

I've trided to use semaphores with

```
sem = threading.BoundedSemaphore()
sem.aquire()
writing to file
compiling
sem.release()
```

but the problem persists

I've looked for a solution but the only ones i found are about databases using transactions

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you use a single file `/home/user/file.c` for every request. so, race condition is imminent.

there are two solutions :

1) write to a temporary file. temporary file can be generated from tempfile module, or you can just create random filename.

2) write to a memory file. you can use `StringIO` (or faster `cStringIO`) module to create such file, and then you can pipe it to gcc.

for solution 1), there are many ways to do this but here's my solution:

change this part

```
data=request.GET.get('content','')
handle=open('/home/user/file.c','r+')
handle.write(request.GET['content'])
handle.close()
```

to

```
# you need 'random', 'string', 'os' modules imported
data=request.GET.get('content','')
filename = "".join(random.sample(string.letters, 10)) + ".c" #sample 10 letters from A-z
filepath = os.path.join('home','user','filename')
handle=open(filepath,'r+')
handle.write(request.GET['content'])
handle.close()
res = commands.getstatusoutput('gcc -Wall %s -o /home/user/file;home/user/file' %filepath)
os.remove(filepath) #remove temporary file after compiling
```

also, the `commands` module is deprecated. you should use `subprocess.call`.

Comment: also, assuming request.GET is a dict-like object, why you do 'get' twice? by `data=request.GET.get('content','')` you safely assign GET values into `data`, and `data` is never used. check: `handle.write(request.GET['content'])`

Answer (score 0):

You should generate random file with each request and use that. The [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module can help you with that.

Also if you don't care about produced binary, using `-o /dev/null` is good idea.